# Comparing data between two dictionaries in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to compare the data in two dictionaries in order to identify keys which have different items.  I'm having difficulty writing out the loop and the if statement to make it that happen.

In the below example, it makes two dictionaries--**BeginningData** and **EndingData**.  The Key "Jane Jones" has a different item in each dictionary.

The output I am looking for in this situation is: *"Jane Jones is 222222222 in the first dictionary, but is 444444444 in the second dictionary"*

Any ideas on how I would complete this code?  I am trying to avoid arrays in this particular project.  Thanks!

```
Sub MainProcess()

Dim BeginningData As Dictionary, EndingData As Dictionary

Dim StartItem As Variant, EndItem As Variant

Set BeginningData = New Dictionary
Set EndingData = New Dictionary

With BeginningData
    .Add "John Smith", 111111111
    .Add "Jane Jones", 222222222
    .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
End With

With EndingData
    .Add "John Smith", 111111111
    .Add "Jane Jones", 444444444
    .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
End With

For Each StartItem In BeginningData.Keys
    For Each EndItem In EndingData.Keys

        'Some sort of if statement here
            Debug.Print _
            GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(EndItem)) & _
            " is " & _
            BeginningData.Item(StartItem) & _
            " in the first dictionary, but is " & _
            EndingData.Item(StartItem) & _
            " in the second dictionary."
        End If

    Next
Next

End Sub

Function GetKey(Dic As Dictionary, strItem As String) As String
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In Dic.Keys
        If Dic.Item(key) = strItem Then
            GetKey = CStr(key)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Of course the second I post about it I figure it out.  The if statement is:

"If GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(StartItem)) = _
        GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(EndItem)) And _
        BeginningData.Item(StartItem) <> EndingData.Item(StartItem) Then"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need neither nested loops nor `GetKey()` function,  just use `Exists()` method of `Dictionary` object to check for a dictionary to contain a given key:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorkingProcess()
    Dim BeginningData As Dictionary, EndingData As Dictionary

    Dim BeginningItem As Variant

    Set BeginningData = New Dictionary
    Set EndingData = New Dictionary

    With BeginningData
        .Add "John Smith", 111111111
        .Add "Jane Jones", 222222222
        .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
    End With

    With EndingData
        .Add "John Smith", 111111111
        .Add "Jane Jones", 444444444
        .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
    End With

    For Each BeginningItem In BeginningData.Keys
        If EndingData.Exists(BeginningItem) Then ' if current "beginning" dict key is in "ending" dict
            If BeginningData.Item(BeginningItem) <> EndingData.Item(BeginningItem) Then ' if items don't match
                Debug.Print _
                BeginningItem & _
                " is " & _
                BeginningData.Item(BeginningItem) & _
                " in the first dictionary, but is " & _
                EndingData.Item(BeginningItem) & _
                " in the second dictionary."
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent.  This operates exponentially faster than my way.

Answer (score 0):

The full working code to compare the two dictionaries and produce the output I needed is:

```
Sub WorkingProcess()

Dim BeginningData As Dictionary, EndingData As Dictionary

Dim StartItem As Variant, EndItem As Variant

Set BeginningData = New Dictionary
Set EndingData = New Dictionary

With BeginningData
    .Add "John Smith", 111111111
    .Add "Jane Jones", 222222222
    .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
End With

With EndingData
    .Add "John Smith", 111111111
    .Add "Jane Jones", 444444444
    .Add "Jim Brown", 333333333
End With

For Each StartItem In BeginningData.Keys
    For Each EndItem In EndingData.Keys

        If GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(StartItem)) = _
        GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(EndItem)) And _
        BeginningData.Item(StartItem) <> EndingData.Item(StartItem) Then
            Debug.Print _
            GetKey(BeginningData, BeginningData.Item(EndItem)) & _
            " is " & _
            BeginningData.Item(StartItem) & _
            " in the first dictionary, but is " & _
            EndingData.Item(StartItem) & _
            " in the second dictionary."
        End If

    Next
Next

End Sub

Function GetKey(Dic As Dictionary, strItem As String) As String
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In Dic.Keys
        If Dic.Item(key) = strItem Then
            GetKey = CStr(key)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```